# Warning:array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in

Tags: php, php7

Tengo el siguiente error:

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in

Estoy usando una función en donde envió los campos a buscar a la BD, con eso genero mi consulta y genero un `while` por cada fila, y un `for` por la cantidad de `items` de la fila. Hasta ahí bien.

El problema es en estas 2 líneas:

```
$array_hijo = array_push($array_hijo, $personas[$partes[$i]]);
$array_padre = array_push($array_padre, $array_hijo);
```

El código completo:

```
function persona($lista) {
    // la cantidad de campos a buscar el la BD
    $partes      = explode(',', $lista);
    $cant        = count($partes);
    $array_padre = array ();
    $array_hijo  = array ();
    $cx          = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT " . $lista . " FROM personas");
    while ($personas = mysqli_fetch_array($cx)):
        for ($i = 0; $i < $cant; $i++) {
            $array_hijo = array_push($array_hijo, $personas[$partes[$i]]);
        }
        $array_padre = array_push($array_padre, $array_hijo);
    endwhile;
    return $array_padre;

}
// puede variar según la cantidad de campos que se desea
$array = persona("nombre,apepat");
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que no debes igualar `$array_hijo` a `array_push`

[array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) pide el arreglo por referencia, es decir el array que le pasas lo modifica directamente en vez de crear una copia, y la documentación dice devuelve la cantidad de elementos en el arreglo. Para añadir un elemento a ese arreglo con `array_push` no hace falta igualarlo, es decir

```
$array_p = [];
array_push($array_p,1)
//$array_p = [1]
```

Como te das cuenta no es necesario volver a igualar `$array_p` con `array_push`

En tu ejemplo al igualarlo `$array_hijo` queda como entero y por eso ahora vale como int.

Quedaría como

```
 for ($i=0; $i < $cant ; $i++) { 
     array_push($array_hijo, $personas[$partes[$i]]);
 }
```

Comment: +1 porque es la única respuesta que contiene información sobre el valor devuelto por `array_push`. Estaria aun mejor resaltaras que al hacer `$array_hijo = array_push` dicha variable pasa dejar de ser un `array` y es esto lo que causa el `warning`

Answer (score 2):

Para que tu método funcione tienes que eliminar la variable, lo haces directamente con:

```
array_push($array_hijo, $personas[$partes[$i]]);
```

Pero te recomiendo hacerlo por medio de:

```
$array_hijo[] = $personas[$partes[$i]];
```

Usando `$arr[] = 'valor';` no requiere una llamada de función e implementa la adición directamente en la estructura de datos. Por lo tanto, cuando se agregan muchos datos es mucho más rápido y eficiente en cuanto a recursos.

Entonces quedaría así:

```
while ($personas = mysqli_fetch_array($cx)):
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cant; $i++) {
        $array_hijo[] = $personas[$partes[$i]];
    }
    $array_padre[] = $array_hijo;
endwhile;
```

Comment: Eduardo Esta genial `$array_hijo[] = $personas[$partes[$i]];` pero me genera un array piramidal por decirlo así : `Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [0] => David [1] => Ramos ) 
 [1] => Array ( [0] => David [1] => Ramos [2] => Sandro [3] => Tello )
 [2] => Array ( [0] => David [1] => Ramos [2] => Sandro [3] => Tello [4] => Rebeca [5] => Huanca )
 [3] => Array ( [0] => David [1] => Ramos [2] => Sandro [3] => Gutierres Tello [4] => Rebeca [5] => Huanca [6] => Aracely [7] => Arjona Donald )`....

Comment: Ya me di cuenta tenia que poner la variable `$array_hijo[]` dentro del `while` para que se limpie

Comment: Cierto fallo mio no poner la var para que se declare vacía. Pero te debe funcionar sin problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Te confieso que me ha costado un rato verlo. Estás utilizando incorrectamente `array_push()`.

No se utiliza así:

```
$array_hijo = array_push($array_hijo, $personas[$partes[$i]]);
```

Sino así:

```
array_push($array_hijo, $personas[$partes[$i]]);
```

En la primera opción sobreescribes `$array_hijo` con el resultado de `array_push()` que será un verdadero. Por tanto, deja de ser array, y aparece ese error.

Digamos que el array que necesita `array_push()` se pasa por referencia, no por valor.